# Vanishing sequence and subsequence with particular decay

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume I have a sequence $\{a_m\}$ that is vanishing and strictly positive:
$$
0<a_{m+1}\leq a_m\leq\ldots\leq a_1<\infty, \quad \lim_{m\to \infty}a_m = 0
$$
Is it true or false that this has a subsequence $\{a_{m_n}\}$ such that
$$
a_{m_n}\asymp n^{-1}
$$
which is to say, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $n$:
$$
\frac{1}{Cn} \leq a_{m_n} \leq \frac{C}{n}
$$

Comment: Isn't this false for any sequence that goes to zero "quickly", e.g., $1/n^2$, or $1/2^n$?

Comment: No, if $a_m=1/m^2$, take $m(n) = \lceil \sqrt{n}\rceil$

Comment: What would the subsequence be for $1/2^n$?

Comment: So you're allowing, say, $m(10)=m(11)=m(12)=\cdots=m(16)$? A subsequence can contain repeated values, even if those values aren't repeated in the source sequence?

Comment: Yes. The subsequence can have repeated values.

Comment: For $1/2^n$, take $m(n) = \lceil \log_2 n\rceil$.  In fact, if we can write $a_m=e^{-\phi(m)}$ and $\phi$ is strictly increasing (i.e., invertible), then $m(n) = \lceil \phi^{-1}(\log n)\rceil$ is satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. E.g., let $a_m:=1/(m!)^2$ and $n_k:=k!(k+1)!$ for natural $m,k$. Your desired condition means that $|\ln na_{m_n}|$ is bounded. In our case, we have 
$$a_{k+1}<\frac1{n_k}<a_k$$
for all $k$. 
So, for all $m\le k$ we have $1<n_k a_k\le n_k a_m$ and hence $|\ln(n_k a_m)|\ge|\ln(n_k a_k)|=\ln(k+1)$. Similarly, for all $m\ge k+1$ we have 
$1>n_k a_{k+1}\ge n_k a_m$ and hence $|\ln(n_k a_m)|\ge|\ln(n_k a_{k+1})|=\ln(k+1)$. So, $|\ln(n_k a_m)|\ge\ln(k+1)$ 
for all $k,m$.

So, for any $(m_n)$
$$|\ln n_ka_{m_{n_k}}|\ge\inf_m|\ln n_k a_m|\ge\ln(k+1)\to\infty$$
as $k\to\infty$, so that $|\ln na_{m_n}|$ is unbounded, for any choice of $(m_n)$.